# How can i set image link without adding it to my project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a webproject where I want to read the `Content/Images/Funny/` for all my funny images :-) I would want to generate a list in my controller of image urls and push it to the view.

How do I access it using relative path from project root? Dont want to use `Server.MapPath` since it will reveal my whole path on the server.

I started a new mvc3 project and Its Content folder I want to map up. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in a controller's action, you can use

```
var path = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Content("~/Content/Images/Funny/");
```